# Как ввести текст в консоль другого приложения из Delphi?

Tags: delphi

При изучении delphi возник вопрос: как работать с процессами? А именно есть игра Counter-Strike 1.6 (думаю, многие знают), в ней есть консоль, которая открывается на букву Ё (как окно), нужно, чтобы при запуске некой программы, которая и выполняет это, выводился текст в консоль. И, в общем, как работать с процессами? Кто знает, подскажите толковые статьи по данному вопросу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Управление чужим приложением Delphi
2. Delphi нажать клавишу в другом приложении

Информации много.

И достань spy ++  из Visual Studio, поможет в разработке.

Comment: Спасибо и за это.)